# Android GoogleTV audio interaction from a background process

Tags: android, google-tv

Is it possible to record the audio coming from the video currently playing?
cable, recorded shows and such

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - No such API exists.  Sorry.

Comment: Les, can you send me a reference?

Comment: I'm in developer relations working on GTV at Google, this has come up before. What kind of reference would you like?

Comment: So what you are actually saying is that there's no way of interacting with the video currently playing?

Comment: Not currently. We hope to have something in the future.  Just to be clear - we are talking about non-internet video.  There are some ways to interact with non DRM'd internet video.

Comment: what are the ways of interacting with a non DRM videos?

Comment: onBufferingUpdateListner() is what I was mainly thinking of, you might be able to intercept bits of the TCP stream.

Comment: off topic question, do you happen to know where can I find an emulator for GTV?

Comment: It's not yet available.  Did you apply for a FishTank?